# Фильтрация вводимых символов в input, регулярные выражения

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Привет!

Что-то не получается у меня с функцией для фильтрации инпута.

```
$('.inputFeature').keypress(function(){
            var txt = $(this).val();

            // только такие символы
            var regx = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я\d.,;:&()*%#\s-]$/;

            if (! txt.match(regx)){
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Помогите пожалуйста, с js пока не очень дружен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('#inputFeature').keypress(function(e){
            // только такие символы
            var regx = /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ\d.,;:&()*%#\s-]$/;
            if (!e.key.match(regx))
                   e.preventDefault();
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id = "inputFeature" type="text"/>
```

далее можно немного сократить `regx` 
до `^[\w\d\sа-яА-ЯёЁ.,;:&()*%#-]$`
неплохой ресурс для помощи в построении регулярных выражений
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)
экспериментируйте далее.

---

update:
как подсказывает @MedvedevDev, в этом случае добавляется `_` и если не критично то можно оставить, а если нужно убрать символ, то можно записать например так: 
`/^(?!_)[\w\sа-яё.,;:&()*%#-]$/gi`

- *- вопросы производительности не учитываем, код в качестве примера*

Comment: Спасибо! Коротко и элегантно. А как можно сделать такой же функционал для copy paste?

Comment: Это смотря чего вы хотите, чтоб не был оффтопик лучше второй вопрос создавать... а так может такое подойдёт  на $("#inputFeature'").bind('copy' или 'paste', function() {что-то делаем}); [а инструкция и описание других событий тут](https://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: нельзя сократить так, ибо `\w` - `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, а по условию задачи нижнее подчеркивание не нужно, единственное сокращение которое могу тут увидеть - поставить флаг `i` и убрать буквы в верхнем регистре.

Comment: полностью с вами согласен, спасибо за замечание, по поводу подчёркивания, просто забыл предупредить, поправлю ответ, оставим на суд автора... по регулярным выражениям много информации отдельно, это уже выходит за рамки вопроса